# Appending a byte into a byte array in Java Card

Tags: byte, javacard

I have a method below to insert a single byte into a byte buffer and during building and cleaning for a Java Card CAP file it throws an error.

Code:

```
private void appendOutputBuffer(byte msg) {
    ArrayLogic.arrayCopyRepack(msg, (short) 0, (short) 0, outputBuffer, (short) outputBuffer.length);
}
```

Error:

```
error: line 163: sctest: class java.lang.Byte not found in export file lang.exp.
error: line 163: sctest: method valueOf(byte) of class java.lang.Byte not found in export file lang.exp or the method signature has changed.
error: line 163: sctest: class java.lang.Byte not found in export file lang.exp.
error: line 163: sctest: class java.lang.Byte in return type of method java.lang.Byte.valueOf(byte) not found.
```

How do I resolve it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not how `arrayCopyRepack` works. Read the documentation: http://www.win.tue.nl/pinpasjc/docs/apis/jc222/javacardx/framework/util/ArrayLogic.html#arrayCopyRepack%28java.lang.Object,%20short,%20short,%20java.lang.Object,%20short%29

Its signature is:

```
public static final short arrayCopyRepack(Object src,
                                          short srcOff,
                                          short srcLen,
                                          Object dest,
                                          short destOff)
```

but the `src` argument is meant to be an array - it is an `Object` just because there is no common ancestor class for all primitive arrays in Java Card. Not everything in Java Card is an `Object`: `byte` is a primitive. That causes your troubles.

The first step of Java Card build is a common Java compiler creating a standard `.class` file. This compiler does not know anything about Java Card and it sees a `byte` used as an `Object`, so it uses autoboxing, casting your `byte` to `java.lang.Byte` and adding a dependence to `java.lang.Byte` in your `.class` file. So far so good. This is just plain Java, so it works.

However, in Java Card libraries there is no `java.lang.Byte` in `java.lang` package. That causes the error when creating a `.cap` file.

---

Appending a byte to an existing array (and thus creating a new array) is a very bad idea, btw. You should create your `buffer` long enough and store the effective length (how long is the used part of the buffer):

```
private static final short BUF_LEN = (short) 256;
byte[] outputBuffer = new byte[BUF_LEN];
...

private void appendOutputBuffer(byte msg) {
    if (effectiveLen == BUF_LEN)
         ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_UNKNOWN);
    outputBuffer[effectiveLen] = msg;
    ++effectiveLen;
}
```

and think about RAM vs EEPROM storing of both `outputBuffer` and `effectiveLen`.